# Unhandle exception in script: module "moviepy.audio.fx.all"

Tags: python, moviepy

I have converted py file to exe. But I have this problem even though in the code I don't use the moviepy module. Please help me.

[Error in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz3jY.png)

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGwOF.png)

Comment: Please post your code and the error as text and not as pictures

Answer (score 0):

I think something in your code is wrong, in case importion I think this moviepy.audio.fx.audio_fadein import audio_fadein should replace this moviepy.audio.fx.all, **because your problem is moviepy.audio.fx.all has no audio_fadein module** and i think audio_fadein in **here** moviepy.audio.fx.audio_fadein import audio_fadein

Just replace this:

```
from moviepy.audio.fx.audio_fadein import audio_fadein
```

If your problem still persists, please share your code where have except.

Comment: I fixed it but still getting the same error.

Comment: @KhangThai Can I see a photo of your error? or show me all your code bro